# FastMM fails to detect memory leaks

Tags: delphi, memory-management, memory-leaks, delphi-5, fastmm

I'm using FastMM 4.97 in my application in Delphi5.

Everything works well, if I run my application from the IDE with an intentional leak for test purposes. I get proper notices and error logs.

However nothing happens if I run my application outside of the IDE (run the .exe file from say Windows Explorer).

Am I missing something? Is this behavior intended? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is expected if `RequireIDEPresenceForLeakReporting` is defined in FastMM4.pas (if Delphi is not running while you're running your program outside the IDE). Also see `InstallOnlyIfRunningInIDE`, if this define is set the default memory manager is used if you run the program outside the IDE (this define is automatically defined if `FullDebugModeInIDE` is defined).

You can use ["FastMM4 Options Interface"](http://jedqc.blogspot.com/2007/07/new-fastmm4-options-interface.html) for easy setting/viewing defines, highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks, Sertac. That interface really saves a lot of time!